# Disabling other slicers in excel when slicer is pressed

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have three slicers operating on a pivot table and pivot chart in excel. However, the filters placed from the two other slicers has to be cleared, when one of the slicers is pressed, assuring that only one slicer is operating at the same time. I think this has to be solved using VBA, listening for a click then executing code, other than that I have no idea as I have never worked with Excel or VBA before.
Anyone got any suggestions on how I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working out what Slicer got clicked is very tricky indeed, because the only application event that gets raised by clicking on a slicer is the PivotTable_Update event. This event tells us which *PivotTable* the slicer is connected to, but not which *field* in that PivotTable got filtered. So if you have multiple silcers connected to a PivotTable, you can't tell which one was just clicked on.

I came up with a very convoluted workaround that I posted at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/10/what-caused-that-pivottableupdate-episode-iv/ that will get you part the way there: it will tell you which field in a PivotTable just got updated, and then you just need to iterate through all the slicers connected to that PivotTable and clear them if they don't have the same sourcename.

I'll see if I can code something up in due course, but I'm pretty busy at present so I can't promise a fast resolution.

Note that you **can** assign a macro directly to a slicer that gets triggered when a user clicks on it, and from that you can determine which slicer it is. But unfortunately that macro interferes with the slicer itself: a user can no longer actually operate the slicer to actually change anything.

---UPDATE---
Here's some code that does what you want. There's a lot of different modules here, because the routine code calls quite a few other generic routines I use. And at it's heart is a routine that works out which particular field of a PivotTable gets updated, and that doesn't care if multilpe fields are filtered.

You call it with this event handler, which goes in the ThisWorkbook module for the book in the Visual Basic Editor:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Slicers_OneSlicerOnly Target
End Sub
```

And that calls these other functions in turn. You don't have to amend anything, and this works on any PivotTables or Slicers you add to this workbook.

```
Function Slicers_OneSlicerOnly(target As PivotTable)
Dim sField As String
Dim slr As Slicer
Dim sSlicer As String
Dim bEnableEvents As Boolean
Dim bScreenUpdating As Boolean
Dim bManualupdate As Boolean
Dim lCalculation As Long
Dim bRecordLayout As Boolean
Dim sLayout_New As String
Dim sLayout_Old As String
Dim lng As Long

With Application
    bEnableEvents = .EnableEvents
    bScreenUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
    lCalculation = .Calculation
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
bManualupdate = target.ManualUpdate
target.ManualUpdate = True
sField = Pivots_FieldChange(target)
If sField <> "" Then
    For Each slr In target.Slicers
        sSlicer = slr.SlicerCache.SourceName
        If sSlicer <> sField Then
            If Not target.PivotFields(sSlicer).AllItemsVisible Then
                target.PivotFields(sSlicer).ClearAllFilters
                bRecordLayout = True
            End If
        End If
    Next slr
End If

target.ManualUpdate = bManualupdate
If bRecordLayout Then
    PivotChange_RecordLayout target, sLayout_New
    With target
        lng = InStr(.Summary, "[Layout]")
        sLayout_Old = Mid(.Summary, lng + Len("[Layout]"), InStr(.Summary, "[/Layout]") - Len("[Layout]") - lng)
        .Summary = Replace(.Summary, "[Layout]" & sLayout_Old & "[/Layout]", "[Layout]" & sLayout_New & "[/Layout]")
    End With
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = bEnableEvents
    .ScreenUpdating = bScreenUpdating
    .Calculation = lCalculation
End With


End Function

Public Function Pivots_FieldChange(target As PivotTable) As String

'   Description:    Works out what caused a PivotTableUpdate event, and if caused by someone changing a filter returns the
'                   name of the PivotField that was filtered.

'   Programmer:     Jeff Weir
'   Contact:        weir.jeff@gmail.com or jeff.weir@HeavyDutyDecisions.co.nz
'   Inputs:         PivotTable
'   Outputs:        String
'   Name/Version:           Date:       Ini:   Modification:
'   PivotChange_20140712    20140712    JSW     Initial programming as per http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/10/what-caused-that-pivottableupdate-episode-iv/
'   PivotChange_20140723    20140423    JSW     Restructured code as per http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/23/broken-arrow/
'   PivotChange_20140802    20140802    JSW     Added: If sLastUndoStackItem = "Filter" Or sLastUndoStackItem = "Slicer Operation" Then
'                                               so that Filter routines only get called in response to filtering
'   Pivots_FieldChange      20151016    JSW     Changed the way info is saved in .summary

    Dim sLastUndoStackItem As String
    Dim sField As String
    Dim sPossibles As String
    Dim sLayout_New As String
    Dim sLayout_Old As String

    On Error Resume Next 'in case the undo stack has been wiped or doesn't exist
    sLastUndoStackItem = Application.CommandBars(14).FindControl(ID:=128).List(1) 'Standard Commandbar, undo stack
    On Error GoTo 0

    If sLastUndoStackItem = "Filter" Or sLastUndoStackItem = "Slicer Operation" Then
        sField = PivotChange_CompareLayout(target, sLayout_New, sLayout_Old)
        If sField = "" Then sField = PivotChange_EliminationCheck(target, sPossibles)
        If sField = "" Then sField = PivotChange_UndoCheck(target, sPossibles)
        If sLayout_Old = "" Then
            target.Summary = "[Layout]" & sLayout_New & "[/Layout]"
        Else
            target.Summary = Replace(target.Summary, "[Layout]" & sLayout_Old & "[/Layout]", "[Layout]" & sLayout_New & "[/Layout]")
        End If
    End If
    Pivots_FieldChange = sField
    Debug.Print Now() & vbTab & "Pivots_FieldChange:" & vbTab & sField


End Function

 Function PivotChange_RecordLayout(pt As PivotTable, ByRef sLayout_New As String) As Boolean

    Dim pf As PivotField

    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
        With pf
            Select Case .Orientation
            Case xlRowField, xlColumnField
                sLayout_New = sLayout_New & .Name & "|" & .VisibleItems.Count & "|" & .VisibleItems(1).Name & "||"
            Case xlPageField
                'pf.VisibleItems.Count doesn't work on PageFields
                'So for PageFields we’ll record what that PageField’s filter currently displays.
                '#DEV# Maybe it's quick to iterate through the .VisibleItems collection (if there is one) and count?
                sLayout_New = sLayout_New & .Name & "|" & .LabelRange.Offset(, 1).Value & "|" & .EnableMultiplePageItems & "||"
            End Select
        End With
    Next pf

    End Function


Function PivotChange_CompareLayout(pt As PivotTable, ByRef sLayout_New As String, ByRef sLayout_Old As String) As String


    Dim i As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    Dim vLayout_Old As Variant
    Dim vLayout_New As Variant

    PivotChange_RecordLayout pt, sLayout_New

    With pt
        lng = InStr(.Summary, "[Layout]")
        If lng > 0 Then
            sLayout_Old = Mid(.Summary, lng + Len("[Layout]"), InStr(.Summary, "[/Layout]") - Len("[Layout]") - lng)
            If sLayout_Old <> sLayout_New Then
                vLayout_Old = Split(sLayout_Old, "||")
                vLayout_New = Split(sLayout_New, "||")
                For i = 0 To UBound(vLayout_Old)
                    If vLayout_Old(i) <> vLayout_New(i) Then
                        PivotChange_CompareLayout = Split(vLayout_Old(i), "|")(0)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Else:
        'Layout has not yet been recorded.
        'Note that we only update .Summary at the end of the main function,
        ' so we don't wipe the UNDO stack before the PivotChange_UndoCheck routine
        End If
    End With

End Function

Function PivotChange_EliminationCheck(pt As PivotTable, ByRef sPossibles As String) As String

    'Check all the visible fields to see if *just one of them alone* has
    ' neither .AllItemsVisible = True nor .EnableMultiplePageItems = false.
    ' If that's the case, then by process of elimination, this field
    ' must be the one that triggered the change, as changes to any of the
    ' others would have been identified in the code earlier.

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim lngFields As Long

    lngFields = 0
    On Error Resume Next ' Need this to handle DataFields and 'Values' field
    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
        With pf
            If .Orientation > 0 Then 'It's not hidden or a DataField
                If .EnableMultiplePageItems And Not .AllItemsVisible Then
                    If Err.Number = 0 Then
                        'It *might* be this field
                        lngFields = lngFields + 1
                        sPossibles = sPossibles & .Name & ";"
                    Else: Err.Clear
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lngFields = 1 Then PivotChange_EliminationCheck = Left(sPossibles, Len(sPossibles) - 1)

End Function




Function PivotChange_UndoCheck(pt As PivotTable, sPossibles) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim dicFields As Object 'This holds a list of all visible pivotfields
    Dim dicVisible As Object 'This contains a list of all visible PivotItems for a pf
    Dim varKey As Variant
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim bidentified As Boolean
    Dim lngVisibleItems As Long


    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Create master dictionary
    Set dicFields = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Cycle through all pivotfields, excluding totals
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(sPossibles, ";")) - 1
        'Create dicVisible: a dictionary for each visible PivotField that contain visible PivotItems
        Set dicVisible = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set pf = pt.PivotFields(Split(sPossibles, ";")(i))
        With pf
        If .Orientation <> xlPageField Then
            For Each pi In .VisibleItems
                With pi
                    dicVisible.Add .Name, .Name
                End With
            Next pi
        Else:
            'Unfortunately the .visibleitems collection isn't available for PageFields
            ' e.g. SomePageField.VisibleItems.Count always returns 1
            ' So we'll have  to iterate through the pagefield and test the .visible status
            ' so we can then record just the visible items (which is quite slow)
             For Each pi In .PivotItems
                With pi
                    If .Visible Then
                        dicVisible.Add .Name, .Name
                    End If
                End With
            Next pi
        End If 'If .Orientation = xlPageField Then
        'Write dicVisible to the dicFields master dictionary
        dicFields.Add .Name, dicVisible
        End With
    Next i

    Application.Undo

    For Each varKey In dicFields.keys
        Set pf = pt.PivotFields(varKey)
        Set dicVisible = dicFields.Item(varKey)

        'Test whether any of the items that were previously hidden are now visible
            If pf.Orientation <> xlPageField Then
                For Each pi In pf.VisibleItems
                    With pi
                        If Not dicVisible.exists(.Name) Then
                            PivotChange_UndoCheck = pf.Name
                            bidentified = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            Else 'pf.Orientation = xlPageField
                lngVisibleItems = dicVisible.Count
                i = 0
                For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
                    With pi
                        If .Visible Then
                            If Not dicVisible.exists(.Name) Then
                                PivotChange_UndoCheck = pf.Name
                                bidentified = True
                                Exit For
                            Else: i = i + 1 'this is explained below.
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                Next

                ' For non-PageFields, we know that the number of .VisibleItems hasn't changed.
                ' But we *don't* know that about Pagefields, and an increase in the amount of
                ' .VisibleItems won't be picked up by our Dictionary approach.
                ' So we'll check if the overall number of visible items changed
                If Not bidentified And i > lngVisibleItems Then
                    PivotChange_UndoCheck = pf.Name
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            If bidentified Then Exit For
        Next

    'Resore the original settings
    With Application
        .CommandBars(14).FindControl(ID:=129).Execute 'Standard Commandbar, Redo command
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With


End Function
End Sub
```

Comment: Slicers update pivot table filters. You could add filters to the pivot table and then you get easily testable changes in Excel cells based on slicer selections. Just store a variable with currently active slicer, and check each filter cell to see which one has now deviated from "All", and change the currently active to "All" and update currently active to be that changed selection.

Comment: So simple, it's genius. Put it as an answer, and I'll vote for it. The solution I proposed above works in the event case where *multiple* fields might have filters applied. But as you've pointed out, that's not the case here, and so your approach will work a treat. Good thinking.

Comment: Just edit it into yours. This was strictly a reaction to your post, not something I would have come up with on my own.

Comment: How I'd implement your concept is have a second PivotTable connected to the first via slicers, with all the fields in that 2nd PivotTable turned into Pagefields (Filter fields). That takes care of the "All" recording. And then just save the states of those alls at every refresh, so on the next refresh you can check how the current state compares to the previous. Pretty similar to what I do above, just simpler. But more limited too...my more complicated code (which is a work in progress) handles more complicated requirements, so I'll leave it as as.